# Raku NativeCall and C source files

Tags: raku, nativecall

What the best strategy to release a Raku binding for C library using NativeCall for both windows and Linux?

Does the developer need to compile both the .dll and .so files and upload them with the raku code to github? Or there are an option on raku like perl to bundle the C source files with Raku code and C compiler will run as part of make and make install?

Comment: Hi @smith. :) .@ugexe's answer looks clear and comprehensive to me, and he's maintaining it (eg he has tweaked it this year to stay ahead of deprecation of the PL name/binary). Is there any reason why you didn't accept it?

Answer (score 6):

The libraries do not need to be compiled first (although they could be). To accomplish this first you'll need a `Build.rakumod` file in the root of your distribution:

```
class Builder {
    method build($dist-path) {
        # do build stuff to your module
        # which is located at $dist-path
    }

    # Only needed for panda compatability
    method isa($what) {
        return True if $what.^name eq 'Panda::Builder';
        callsame;
    }
}
```

Then you'll want to use a module like [LibraryMake](https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-LibraryMake). Here we use it's `make` routine in the `build` method:

```
use LibraryMake;

class Builder {
    method build($dist-path) {
        make($dist-path, "$dist-path/resources");

        # or you could do the appropriate `shell` calls
        # yourself and have no extra dependencies
    }

    ...
```

This method is supported by the package managers [zef](https://github.com/ugexe/zef) and [panda](https://github.com/tadzik/panda), and also allows it to be manually ran via `raku -I. -MBuild -e 'Builder.new.build($*CWD)'`

[Here](https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-Compress-Zlib-Raw/blob/master/Build.pm) is a working example